# Integrating Aurigma Express in Zend

Tags: php, aurigma

First of all hello :).

Spend two days trying to integrate  [Aurigma Express](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/ImageUploaderExpress/)  version PHP code.

Mentions

I am using Zend Framework.

I don't get it why the code looks that bad .If you want a clean version here it is [CodePad](http://codepad.org/BHTiq2VJ)

I've managed to make the think to be `visible` but it fails to do what `upload.php` should do .

Note : This is in the Controller

`function onFileUploaded($uploadedFile) {
  $absGalleryPath = realpath($this->_path) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

  $originalFileName = $uploadedFile->getSourceName();
  $files = $uploadedFile->getConvertedFiles();
  $sourceFile = $files[0];
  if ($sourceFile){
  $sourceFile->moveTo($absGalleryPath . $originalFileName);
  }
}`

public function uploadImagesAction(){

```
$this->_session->message = $this->_session->messages['message_backend_product_image_notification_succesfully_added'];

require_once ROOT_PATH . "/Aurigma/ImageUploaderPHP/UploadHandler.class.php";
require_once ROOT_PATH . "/Aurigma/ImageUploaderPHP/UploadedFile.class.php";

$product_id = $this->_getParam('prod');
$product = Model_Product::getById($product_id);
$this->_path = "http://rstcenter.com/forum/images/products/".$product['id']."/";
$uploadHandler = new UploadHandler();

$uploadHandler->saveFiles(realpath($this->_path));

$uploadHandler->setFileUploadedCallback('onFileUploaded');

$uploadHandler->processRequest();
```

}

Any ideas are welcomed :). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Since in Zend Framework the code placed inside controller class, function *onFileUploaded* is not a global function anymore, but a class member. And callback should be added like:

```
$uploadHandler->setFileUploadedCallback(array($this, 'onFileUploaded'));
```

See <s>`http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#example-86`</s>(dead link) article about callbacks in PHP.